# How can Cases detect x as Times[1,x]

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials, filtering

I'm trying to use `Cases` to extract the coefficients of a polynomial
$$x^5+6x^4+2x^3-8x^2+x+10$$
I was hoping I can first find the coefficients of the $x,\,x^2,\,...,\,x^5$, then use `DeleteCases` to find the constant $10$. I tried this code but can only get the cases in which the coefficient is not equal to 1

```
In[1]:  poly = x^5 + 6 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 8 x^2 + x + 10;  
In[2]:  Map[Cases[poly, Times[a_, x^#] :> a, Infinity] &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]  
Out[3]: {{}, {-8}, {2}, {6}, {}}
```

How can I detect the coefficient which has the value of 1?

Comment: For all coefficients, try CoefficientList[x^5 + 6 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 8 x^2 + x + 10, x] or if you just want the constant, try f = x^5 + 6 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 8 x^2 + x + 10;Coefficient[f, x, 0]

Comment: I believe you may be looking for the documentation on [`OneIdentity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html).  Does that appear to answer your question?

Comment: try `Map[Cases[poly, Times[a_., x^#] :> a, 1] &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
poly = x^5 + 6 x^4 + 2 x^3 - 8 x^2 + x + 10;
```

With [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[poly, Alternatives @@ (a_. x^{_, 1, 0}) :> a]
```

> {10, 1, -8, 2, 6, 1}

and to isolate the constant with [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
DeleteCases[poly, Alternatives @@ (a_. x^{_, 1})]
```

> 10

Or with [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html)

```
CoefficientList[poly, x]
```

> {10, 1, -8, 2, 6, 1}

and the constant with

```
Coefficient[poly, x, 0]
```

> 10

or with the (undocumented in 10.1) functionality

```
CoefficientList[poly, x, 1]
```

> {10}